# What is the encryption function in Encfs?

Tags: filesystems, encryption, fuse, encfs

After I read a paper about Encfs, I figured out there is a Encryption layer in Encfs.
So I tried to find exact encryption function. but I couldn't find that because there are many functions. 
Does anyone have any idea or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation, the encryption cipher used is configuration dependent and as I understand could be any (symmetric) cipher the underlying encryption library supports:

```
Cipher
  Which encryption algorithm to use.  The list is generated automatically based on
  what supported algorithms EncFS found in the encryption libraries.  When using a
  recent version of OpenSSL, Blowfish and AES are the typical options.

  Blowfish is an 8 byte cipher - encoding 8 bytes at a time.  AES is a 16 byte
  cipher.
```